# Preventing deletion/removal of android service ever after factory reset

Tags: android, android-intent, factory, reset, android-pendingintent

I am creating one android service that runs forever in background. And I don't want it to be deleted/removed even after factory reset of the phone. How can I achieve this in android code? Is there any intent for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any intent for this?

Fortunately, no, for blindingly obvious security reasons.

> And I don't want it to be deleted/removed even after factory reset of the phone. How can I achieve this in android code?

Build your own custom ROM that contains your app pre-installed. Install that custom ROM on your device.